# What is a word for ascribing divine characteristics to a machine?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

We use *anthropomorphize* to describe when human qualities have been ascribed to non-human creatures, objects, etc.

What is a word to that captures the situation when seemingly divine (or godlike) qualities have been ascribed to machines or software?

Usage: Many of the responses to the chess match between Google's AlphaZero and Stockfish - or more precisely, the responses to some of the moves played by the former in said match - seem to be delivered in a register that _____ AlphaZero. For example, Nigel Short wrote: "[On seeing the engine's games, I feel like I am in the presence of God.](https://twitter.com/nigelshortchess/status/1073685765073326084?s=09)"

Comment: _Deus in machinam_?

Comment: Yes, that also works very well in the same context.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is a rare word "theomorphise"/"theomorphize" which according to the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200394?redirectedFrom=theomorphize#eid18816928) means:

> **theoˈmorphize**  v. (transitive) to form in the image of God.

Comment: This is better than deify. To deify is to actually look to something as godlike, to theomorphize is to regard someone's interaction with something else as being close to worship. Would +2 if I could.

Comment: I don't see how the OED's definition of theomorphize fits the OP's context. The OP wasn't talking about someone forming AlphaZero in the image of God, but rather someone talking about AlphaZero with a level of reverence and awe akin to worship. Maybe *theomorphize* can also mean something more analogous to *anthropomorphize*, but that meaning isn't what the quoted definition shows.

Answer (score 35):

*[Deify](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deify)*, as defined by Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary 11th edition, fits the example given. It can mean any of the following:

> 1: 
>   a: to make a god of
>   b: to take as an object of worship
>   2: to glorify as of supreme worth

Comment: The definitions here seem to fit the OP's meaning and context better than that of *theomorphize*.

Answer (score 9):

The word that came to my mind was *apotheosis*, [The fact or action of becoming or making into a god](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apotheosis) (Wiktionary). But this is a noun, not a verb. Wiktionary does, however, also give the rarer word [apotheosize](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apotheosize), which fits your sentence well.

Answer (score 4):

Try [divinise](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divinize). (Or divinize, in the US.) It means precisely to ascribe divine qualities.